# Can't figure out why private member from header file isn't working in cpp file

Tags: c++, header, private, member

Hi I've been searching all over the place for the fix to this issue and have tried multiple different ways of defining the ListNode in the .cpp file. For some reason the struct can't be shared with the .cpp file.  Any help will be greatfully appreciated.
Thanks

.H FILE:

```
#ifndef SORTEDLIST_H
#define SORTEDLIST_H

#include "Student.h"

/*
 * SortedList class
 *
 * A SortedList is an ordered collection of Students.  The Students are ordered
 * from lowest numbered student ID to highest numbered student ID.
 */
class SortedList {

  public:

    SortedList();
    // Constructs an empty list.

bool insert(Student *s);
// If a student with the same ID is not already in the list, inserts 
// the given student into the list in the appropriate place and returns
// true.  If there is already a student in the list with the same ID
// then the list is not changed and false is returned.

Student *find(int studentID);
// Searches the list for a student with the given student ID.  If the
// student is found, it is returned; if it is not found, NULL is returned.

Student *remove(int studentID);
// Searches the list for a student with the given student ID.  If the 
// student is found, the student is removed from the list and returned;
// if no student is found with the given ID, NULL is returned.
// Note that the Student is NOT deleted - it is returned - however,
// the removed list node should be deleted.

void print() const;
// Prints out the list of students to standard output.  The students are
// printed in order of student ID (from smallest to largest), one per line

private:

// Since ListNodes will only be used within the SortedList class,
// we make it private.
struct ListNode {    
  Student *student;
  ListNode *next;
};

ListNode *head; // pointer to first node in the list
};

#endif
```

.CPP FILE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SortedList.h"

using namespace std;


SortedList::SortedList() : head(NULL){}



Student SortedList::*find(int studentID){
ListNode *current;
current = head;
if(current != NULL){
 while(current != NULL){
               if(current.student.getID() == studentID){
               return current.student;
               }
 current = current.next;
 }
}
return NULL;                   
}
```

RELEVANT ERRORS:
     C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\SortedList.cpp In function `Student SortedList::* find(int)': 
    12 C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\SortedList.cpp`ListNode' undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: Is that really the *first* error you got from that code? Always work your way through the errors in order. When the compiler encounters an error, it makes certain assumptions about what you meant so that it can continue trying to compile and give you more error messages, but sometimes, later errors are just side effects of a bad assumption from the compiler. If you start working on errors from the middle of the list, you might end up wasting time trying to fix things that aren't really errors. Always start at the top.

Comment: The above is good advice, however I test-compiled this myself (with a stub definition of Student) and it really was the first error.  The OP managed to find one of the really *sneaky* guns that C++ provides for the purpose of shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: And here's some advice of my own: In the future, when you have another problem you don't understand and you want to ask for help, the first thing you should do is try to cut your code down to the *smallest program possible* that produces the same error.  It's almost always possible to get it down to one file and less than 20 lines.  You may well realize what the problem is in the process of doing this, and even if you don't, it will be easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error you're getting is sort of misleading; your problem isn't related to `ListNode` at all.  You've got a syntax error in your cpp file:

```c++
Student *SortedList::find(int studentID)
```

This means that `SortedList::find` returns a pointer to a student.

Comment: It's technically not a syntax error, but a declaration of the wrong function.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
Student SortedList::*find(int studentID) {
```

You put the star in the wrong place.  This is *not* the preamble to the definition of `SortedList::find`, returning a `Student*`.  This is the preamble to the definition of a *free function* named `find`, which returns a `Student SortedList::*`.  (an unusual, but well-formed, "pointer-to-member" type).  Because it's not a SortedList member method, none of SortedList's inner declarations are in scope, and that's why you get that confusing error message.

This is what you should have written:

```
Student *
SortedList::find(int studentID)
{
```

(Breaking it up into three lines like that is not necessary, but will make it easier for other people to read your code.)

Answer (score 0):

The correct signature is:

```
Student* SortedList::find(int studentID)
```

The pointer is part of the return type, not part of the method name.